# 'Item' is of type 'unknown' in vue3 v-for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

[image]

im trying to do a v-for loop but its showing this error on vue3 + typescript project

this is a component and im passing props like this

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue"

defineProps({
  margin: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  futurecashflow: {
    type: Array,
    default: [1,2]
  },
});
</script>
```

i tried everything, this error wasnt present before like a week ago this is apperaing out of no where

Comment: try `type: Array as PropType<Array<number>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the props and then calling props.futurecashflow

```
import {ref,defineProps} from "vue"


let props= defineProps({
  margin: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  discountrate: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },

  futurecashflow: {
    default: [1,2]
  },
  
});
```

and callingon v-for like

```
<tbody class="table-auto" v-for="(item, index) in props.futurecashflow">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using TypeScript, you should use the [TypeScript-only features](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features). Define an interface of your props, then add the defaults with `withDefaults`:

```
interface Props {
    margin: number;
    futurecashflow: number[];
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    margin: 1,
    futurecashflow: [1, 2],
});
```