# Vue3 v-for item returning unkown type

Tags: typescript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm reading Laravel bootcamp and studding the tutorial, but I get some erro on showing the model with vuejs and v-for.
My code:

```
type ChirpModel = {
  id: number,
  message: string,
  created_at: string,
  user: {
      user_id: number,
      name: string
    }
  }
const props = defineProps<{ chirps: Array<ChirpModel> }>()
```

and the v-for tags

```
        <div class="mt-6 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-lg divide-y">
            <Chirp v-for="c in props.chirps" :key="c.id" :chirp="c" />
        </div>
```

And Im getting the type error:

[image]

Can someone give me where to look for the solution? any tip is apreciated

I has looking into on forums but cant find where Im doing wrong

I find this ask here ['Item' is of type 'unknown' in vue3 v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234237/item-is-of-type-unknown-in-vue3-v-for-loop) but Im using Typescript and in this example thit not worked

Answer (score 1):

Inside the template you will write without props, like this:

```
 <Chirp v-for="c in chirps" :key="c.id" :chirp="c" />
```

Comment: Same result. Its anoying because is correctly typed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **export** the defined type:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
export type ChirpModel = {
  id: number,
  message: string,
  created_at: string,
  user: {
      user_id: number,
      name: string
    }
  };
defineProps<{ chirps: Array<ChirpModel> }>()
</script>
```

And as meir mentioned, you can just use chirps directly.

```html
 <Chirp v-for="c in chirps" :key="c.id" :chirp="c" />
```